# bootstrap form required field

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap form like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
                <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="required col-xs-10" >
                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now the name field is required so i want to display an asterisk right next to it. I tried this:

```
.required:after {
    content: " *";
}
```

But it is displayed under the input, not right next to it. How can i fix this?
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dc5yw/

Comment: do you want * next to text name or next to input?

Comment: It should be next to the input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reduce the width of the input fields `form-control` and add `float:left` to this.

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/u484K/)

CSS changes

```
.required:after {
    content: "*";
    padding-left:1%;
}

.form-control{
    width:97%;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check this fiddle.this will solve ur problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dc5yw/1/

change this

```
<div class="required col-xs-10" >
<input class="form-control1" type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.required::after {
 content: "*";
 position:absolute;
 right:0px;
 top:10px;
}
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Dc5yw/6/)

*side note: `:after` is old syntax, now it is  [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter)*

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dc5yw/3/)**

**CSS**

```
.col-xs-10 {
    position:relative;
}
.required:after {
    content:" *";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: without making changes in previous CSS just additional position:relative; on .col-xs-10

Answer (score -1):

In your HTML

```html
<div class="form-group required">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Name<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">
                                
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This adds the required parameter while the user ask about displaying an asterisk next to an input field. Please always include an elaborate description of your code in your answer so it can be helpful